# Excel Sheet reading (Particular cell)?

Tags: excel, sax, saxparser, poi-hssf, hssf

How to read certain text font (for specific subscript, superscript uppercase lowercase, italic bold etc.) in a particular cell's. (Not for complete cell, or not to set that format for complete cell)?

like for Example: I have a cell in a spreadsheet (Excel sheet), in which user write some text (string) in uppercase, some of the text is written in lowercase or some of it in bold, italic or may be different in size or its font style is change. I want to read that cell's text as it is in same formatting.

text in cell: LIKE user's *Ques* and **ABOVE?**
After reading complete cell string should look: LIKE user's *Ques* and **ABOVE?**

Comment: need more explanation for better answers

Comment: Do you want the text, the formatting, or both? And what format do you want the formatting in?

Comment: Yes, I want to read both (text with formatting) from the cell. (FYI I want to fetch the string as it is from the xls document sheet's cell.)